# Qt 4.5 third-party installer programs

Tags: qt, installation, windows-installer, qt-creator

Are there any good setup builders for Qt 4.5 projects on Windows? I have heard there is an installer that you just point at your Qt Creator project, and it figures out the dependancies and creates an .MSI setup file. I haven't located anything like that so far.

What are others using?

Answer (score 2):

[Bitrock](http://bitrock.com/) is written in Qt, and has very good support for Qt projects. It's cross platform, and rocks hard. It's a commercial product, but worth every penny. You can try a free version from their website.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) along with [ISTool](http://www.istool.org/). However, dependency resolution has to be done manually. There is also [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page).